# objectAtIndex:indexPath.row method always causes exception in IOS

Tags: ios, xcode, uitableview, plist

Hi I always seem to get exception when I use objectAtInded method to retrieve NSString from an array. I am reading data from a dictionary which is in the "PropertyList.plist" file.My code is

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    NSString *path = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"PropertyList"
                                                     ofType:@"plist"];
    names = [[NSDictionary alloc]
             initWithContentsOfFile:path];

    keys = [[[names allKeys] sortedArrayUsingSelector:
             @selector(compare:)] retain];
}


-(UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    NSUInteger section = [indexPath section];
    NSUInteger row = [indexPath row];

    NSString *key  = [keys objectAtIndex:section];
    NSArray *nameSection = [names objectForKey:key];
    static NSString *SectionsTableIdentifier = @"SectionsTableIdentifier";
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:SectionsTableIdentifier];
    if(cell == nil)
    {
        cell = [[[UITableViewCell alloc]
                 initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:SectionsTableIdentifier] autorelease];
    }
    cell.textLabel.text = [nameSection objectAtIndex:row];
    return cell;
}
```

The exception happens on the method "cellForRowAtIndexPath" in the line

```
cell.textLabel.text = [nameSection objectAtIndex:row];
```

The error message is

> Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[__NSCFDictionary objectAtIndex:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x6832440

The plist file is 
[image]

Where ever I use "[nameSection objectAtIndex:row];" type of statement it always get exception.

Comment: Because here compiler is taking nameSection as an NSDictionary not as NSArray.And calling objectAtIndex: on a dictionary object is throwing an exception.You have to cross check the structure of your PropertyList plist.

Comment: How can I take the value of nameSection as an array? I tried doing what #Jasmeet Singh said which is NSMutableArray *nameSection = (NSMutableArray*)[names objectForKey:key]; but it shows the same exception!

Comment: i am saying to cross check your plist structure.                          [names objectForKey:key] function is returning a NSDictionary object instead of an NSArray.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Like @scorpiozj said 'names' contains only key of 'Root'. So what I did I know is not a very good way to do it. I am sure there is some other way. I changed the 'viewDidLoad' method to this,

```
 - (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    NSString *path = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"PropertyList"
                                                     ofType:@"plist"];
    names = [[NSDictionary alloc]
             initWithContentsOfFile:path];
    keys = [names allKeys];
    NSString *key = [keys objectAtIndex:0];
    names = [names objectForKey:key];
    keys = [[[names allKeys] sortedArrayUsingSelector:@selector(compare:)] retain];
    NSLog(@"keys = %@  names = %@",keys,names);
}
```

It works! Any idea how to do it better will be appreciated though.

Answer (score 2):

The reason for this can be following

1. [names objectForKey:key];. This statement could give output a NSMutableDictionary type and you are taking a NSArray from that. OR
2. If it is an array then use the below code for getting the nameSection

   ```
      NSMutableArray *nameSection = (NSMutableArray*)[names objectForKey:key];
      // using (NSMutableArray*) before the code is for external typecasting to tell the compiler that the output is of NSMutableArray type.
   ```

Hope this helps.

EDIT:-

use the method below to get your dictionary from the plist file

```
        -(NSMutableDictionary *) GetDictDataFromPlistFile:(NSString *) fileName
       {
             NSError *error;
             NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES); //1
             NSString *documentsDirectory = [paths objectAtIndex:0]; //2
             NSString *path = [documentsDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@.plist",fileName]]; //3

              NSFileManager *fileManager = [NSFileManager defaultManager];

            if (![fileManager fileExistsAtPath: path]) //4
            {
                   NSString *bundle = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:fileName ofType:@"plist"]; //5
                  [fileManager copyItemAtPath:bundle toPath: path error:&error]; //6
             }

              NSMutableDictionary *dictData =   [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] initWithContentsOfFile:path];

               return dictData;
        }
```

Comment: Changed the code to NSMutableArray *nameSection = (NSMutableArray*)[names objectForKey:key]; but still same exception!

Comment: For this we should know the structure of your plist file. NSLog(@"%@", nameSection); use this after the line NSArray *nameSection = [names objectForKey:key]; and see what it prints.

Answer (score 1):

Here, `name` contains only one key of `root`.
What you need for `name` is the value of key `Root`.
Please retry!